# Special Character in Json

Tags: java, android, json

i consume a webservice which i don't have enough control over it , so i have to parse what it returns! here is the parsing section :

```
        HttpResponse getResponse =  httpclient.execute(httpPost);  
        HttpEntity returnEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        is = returnEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 128);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        result = result.replaceAll("^\"(.*)\"$","$1");
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); //this line throws error
```

last line make an exception :

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 1 of {\r\n  \"xUserPW\": \"EmU7cU\"\r\n}
```

and the result String is :

```
{\r\n  \"xUserPW\": \"EmU7cU\"\r\n}
```

how can i prevent this exception?

Comment: Are those actual linebreaks or is there the literal `String` `\r\n` in the JSON?

Comment: What Boris said:  The value of `result` should be `{"xUserPW": "dStT0T"}`

Comment: Why are you modifying the response from the web-service?

Comment: @selbie and Boris : the result which i've got from webservice was this string : "{\r\n  \"xUserPW\": \"dStT0T\"\r\n}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the json.org : http://json.org/

in that site the json defined in the side menu i just go along the path thats relevant to your problem:

```
object -> { members }    // each object replaces by { members }
members  -> pair      // each  members  replaces by pair
pair ->  string : value  // and so on ...
string -> "chars"
" chars " -> char chars
char -> any-Unicode-character-
        except-"-or-\-or-
        control-character  \"  \\  \/  \b \f \n \r \t \u four-hex-digits
```

so your json must not begin by control characters, but i checked it and in other json validators it is ok for example in :
http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html 
but in json.org it is not. so just remove `\r\n` from begining and the end.

Answer (score 2):

> and the result String is : {\r\n  \"xUserPW\": \"dStT0T\"\r\n}

This is not a valid json format. Is webservice returning you json? You cannot simply append \n to received data and convert it.

```
HttpResponse getResponse =  httpclient.execute(httpPost);  
    HttpEntity returnEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
    is = returnEntity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 128);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

should not thow errors

Comment: i've thought about that there is not a valid Json , but i was asking maybe there is someway to handle the issue.

Comment: Do you add Accept:application/json header to your HttpGet request? mHttpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: its a post which i've added : httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

Comment: in case it is server failure and it indeed sends invalid response body, try replacing \, \n, and \r one by one. smth. like result.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\", "");

Comment: its a dirty hack to replace all \n and \r with "" ;) . i think better way is calling to the man who make this result!

Answer (score 1):

`JSONException: Expected literal value at character` means that the .json returned must be invalid!

this is an invalid .json format:

```
{\r\n \"xUserPW\": \"dStT0T\"\r\n}
```

Comment: webservice is not mine , so you think the problem is from the webservice right?